# How I get all nodes in my ASP.NET Application for the TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, treeview, nodes

i try in my windows form application to use a treeView with a xml string that i get from the xmlreader and filter them to his nodes. It works and my Problem is I want do this now in a asp.net application but on line is ot the same how in win forms.

In my Windows Form application:

```
...
public void LoadTree(XElement root, TreeNode rootNode)
        {
            foreach (var e in root.Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("NAME") != null))
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(e.Attribute("NAME").Value);


                rootNode.Nodes.Add(node); // <---- 


                LoadTree(e, node);
            }
        }
...
```

Here my asp.net application:

```
private void LoadTree(XElement root, TreeNode rootNode)
        {
            foreach (var e in root.Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("NAME") != null))
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(e.Attribute("NAME").Value);

                rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(node); //<----

                LoadTree(e, node);
            }
        }
```

The Problem is that I get not the same treeview how in my windows Forms application because it is missing the nodes under the nodes that I get in my asp.net application :(

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LM-X STAT_VERSION="3.32">
<LICENSE_PATH TYPE="NETWORK" HOST="serv005" SERVER_VERSION="4.4.4" UPTIME="53 day(s) 21 hour(s) 10 min(s) 50 sec(s)">
<FEATURE NAME="GlobalZoneEU" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR" START="2013-03-26" END="2014-03-31" USED_LICENSES="111720" TOTAL_LICENSES="147000" SHARE="CUSTOM ,VIRTUAL">
<USER NAME="SYSTEM" HOST="LRV171" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" SHARE_CUSTOM="hweuser:172.16.11.115"/>
>
<USER NAME="pbsadmin" HOST="SERV11" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="720" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:44" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:44" SHARE_CUSTOM="pbsadmin:LWSERV171:1592_40960072_1356792762_826820"/>
...
```

Comment: If you could post your XML string and the treeview output that's expected, it would be helpful

Comment: look to my update....